# i keep getting this error everytime i run this block of code

Tags: scripting, discord, discord.js

this is my code.

```
client.on('message', e =>{
    if(e.member.role.cache.has('960191891473829929')){
    if(!e.content.startsWith(p) || e.author.bot) return;
    console.log('successfully unmuted')
    var ar = e.content.slice(p.length).split(/ +/)
    var cmd = ar.shift().toLowerCase();
    if(cmd === 'us'){
    var target = e.mentions.users.first();
    if(target){
        let mainRole = e.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'retard')
        let muteRole = e.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'commoner')

        let memberTarget = e.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);

        memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id)
        memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id)
        var smbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('GREEN')
        .setTitle('success!')
        .setDescription(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been successfully unmuted!`)
        e.channel.send({embeds: [smbed]})
    } else{
        var fembed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RED')
        .setTitle('invalid user!')
        .setDescription('unmute failed because there was not a valid member mentioned :(')
        e.channel.send({ embeds: [fembed] })
    }
    }
} else {
    e.channel.send({embeds: [rolefb]})
}
});
```

and this is the error im getting.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')
```

please help, don't know how to fix. ive tried everything it would mean a lot if just ONE person helped

its supposed to mute somebody with the id role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small typo here :

```js
    if(e.member.role.cache.has('960191891473829929')){
```

add a `s` after `role` :

```js
    if(e.member.roles.cache.has('960191891473829929')){
```